# Restrict a text box to allow special characters at starting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate a text box  which i am using for search the content which comes from database.Need to restrict special characters at starting but allow after a word.And space also.

Ex: Must allow 
    `java/j2ee`
    `java&servlets`

But Not
     `@java`
     `$java`
     `(space)java`

```
$("#keyvalue").keypress(function (e) { 

  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_ .-]*$");
  var regex1 =new RegExp("[,%_$]"); 
  var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode); 

  if (!regex.test(key)){

    $("#errormess").html("Please select valid input").show();
  } 

  if(regex1.test(key)) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
  } else { 

  $("#errormess").html(""); 
  }

});
```

Comment: Show your attempted code. This is not a service.

Comment: "special character" is such a bizarre phrase.  is "q" a special character?  is "あ"?  why?

Comment: $("#keyvalue").keypress(function (e) {

       var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_ .-]*$");
       var regex1 =new RegExp("[,%_$]");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
          if (!regex.test(key)) 
          {
            $("#errormess").html("Please select valid input").show();
          } 
          if(regex1.test(key))
           {
           e.preventDefault();
           }
          else
          { 
           
           $("#errormess").html("");
          }

Comment: Above code i tried,it restricted but not allowing after words.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function isValid(){
    return !/[@$\s\/&]/g.test(yourString.indexOf(0));
    // Returns true if special char not exists at first position
}
```

You can add more special characters in `[@$\s\/&]`

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\s]+)$/;
if(!pattern.test(textbox.value)){
    console.log('Not allowed!');
}
```

or this one, having less complex regex

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9].*)$/;
if(!pattern.test(textbox.value)){
    console.log('Not allowed!');
}
```